# Getting fireStore error while running project

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

I am new to angular and firestore database I first started working with Realtime Database but now I want to work with firestore so I wasn't able to find the imports of angular firestore so I run this command

```
ng add @angular/fire

npm install --save firebase @angular/fire
```

Also deleted package-lock.json

and re run the command like

```
npm-i
```

and also `npm-update`

tried to find the various solutions to remove the below error but didn't get success

The error is below which I get when I run the command `ng serve`

> This likely means that the library (@angular/fire/firestore) which declares AngularFirestore has not been processed correctly by ngcc, or is not compatible with Angular Ivy. Check if a newer version of the library is available, and update if so. Also consider checking with the library's authors to see if the library is expected to be compatible with Ivy.

also got this one

> ERROR in node_modules/@angular/fire/firestore/firestore.d.ts:85:22 -
> error NG6002: Appears in the  NgModule.imports of AppModule, but could
> not be resolved to an NgModule class.

Let me know if anyone has a better solution.

For the better understanding please head to this post

[couldnt import fireStoreModule correctly in angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63130954/couldnt-import-firestoremodule-correctly-in-angular?noredirect=1#comment111647016_63130954)

Comment: please post your package.json

Comment: Actually if you can, create a stackblitz project with all the relevant code, as this might be a deeply linked issue

Comment: Stackblitz gives button for adjusting imports where I particulary see the problem is somwhere related to imports which vs code couldnt recognize or not being properly done

Answer (score -1):

I'd say that you can follow the [tutorial installation](https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/master/docs/install-and-setup.md) from a cleaner environment.

I've already tried it and I was able to deploy the welcome page pretty much smoothly. So I think you could try to run that sample and identify the relevant differences, maybe there are some versions mismatching in compatibility.

I would point out that the error posted looks more related with the way you are importing the libraries, I've found this [github issue](https://github.com/angular/angularfire/issues/2351) with the same error message in it seems it was related to the imports.

I've seen your package.json at the mentioned SO post and I think it looks fine, I've noticed you are using one version before the latest.

Comment: Can you have a look to this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63130954/couldnt-import-firestoremodule-correctly-in-angular?noredirect=1#comment111647016_63130954

Comment: Let me know the next steps I really wasted lot of time doing this stuffs..!!

Comment: deleted node modules and package-lock.json and did npm install by adding dependency Actually using version 10 of Angular as firestore is supported in version 9+

Comment: @kushalBaldev I've answered at the chat an updated my answer. Could you give a look?

Comment: Sure thanks for the answer I will make the changes accordingly and let you know :)