# couldnt import fireStoreModule correctly in angular

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angular8, angular10

I am getting this error while running the angular project

> This likely means that the library (@angular/fire/firestore) which
> declares AngularFirestore has not been processed correctly by ngcc, or
> is not compatible with Angular Ivy. Check if a newer version of theen
> processed correctly by ngcc, or is not compatible with Angular Ivy.
> Check if a newer version of the library is available, and update if
> so. Also consider checking with the library's authors to see if  the
> library is expected to be compatible with Ivy

I just read this line in from here https://github.com/angular/angularfire/releases

AngularFirestoreModule no longer imports firebase/firestore on it's own to remain side-effect free, you'll need to import 'firebase/firestore' on your own

what does it mean how can I run the project successfully?

the below is my package.json and I am using angular version 10 the latest one and the @angular/fire":version is 6.0.2

```
{
  "name": "angular10-app",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~10.0.5",
    "@angular/cdk": "^9.2.4",
    "@angular/common": "~10.0.5",
    "@angular/compiler": "~10.0.5",
    "@angular/core": "~10.0.5",
    "@angular/fire": "^6.0.2",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "^9.0.0-beta.31",
    "@angular/forms": "~10.0.5",
    "@angular/material": "^9.2.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~10.0.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~10.0.5",
    "@angular/router": "~10.0.5",
    "@kolkov/angular-editor": "^1.1.2",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^12.1.2",
    "angular-split": "^3.0.3",
    "angularfire": "^2.3.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.5.0",
    "firebase": "^7.17.1",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "^5.6.1",
    "ngx-translate-multi-http-loader": "^3.0.0",
    "querybase": "^0.6.0",
    "rxjs": "~6.5.4",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/architect": "^0.1000.4",
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.1000.4",
    "@angular/cli": "~10.0.4",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~10.0.5",
    "@angular/language-service": "~10.0.5",
    "@types/jasmine": "^3.5.11",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "^12.12.53",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.0",
    "firebase-tools": "^8.0.0",
    "fuzzy": "^0.1.3",
    "inquirer": "^6.2.2",
    "inquirer-autocomplete-prompt": "^1.0.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.5.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "~5.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "~3.3.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
    "open": "^7.1.0",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "~3.9.7"
  }
}
```

Actually I have updated my project recently but in the previous version that is 9 the firestore didnt seem to work..!!

below are the bunch of commands I used to update project and use firebase

```
1. ng update @angular/cli
2. ng update @angular/core
3. ng add @angular/fire   //By adding this its written that I will get the latest version
```

the link https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular/fire

finally once I did `npm update`

then deleted package-lock.json

then run command `npm i`

the below is my app module.ts

```
   //import { AngularFirestore } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
    import {AngularFireDatabaseModule} from '@angular/fire/database';
    import {AngularFireModule} from '@angular/fire';
    import 'firebase/firestore';
    //import { AngularFirestoreModule} from '@angular/fire/firestore';
    
    imports: [
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebase),
        AngularFireDatabaseModule,
        //AngularFirestore,
        //AngularFirestoreModule,
    ],
    providers: [],
      bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
    export class AppModule{

    }
```

If I comment this imports the project runs fine but if I uncomment this imports then there is an error.

**EDIT-1**

now my package.json looks like

```
{
  "name": "angular9-app",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~10.0.5",
    "@angular/cdk": "^9.2.4",
    "@angular/common": "~10.0.5",
    "@angular/compiler": "~10.0.5",
    "@angular/core": "~10.0.5",
    "@angular/fire": "^6.0.2",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "^9.0.0-beta.31",
    "@angular/forms": "~10.0.5",
    "@angular/material": "^9.2.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~10.0.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~10.0.5",
    "@angular/router": "~10.0.5",
    "@kolkov/angular-editor": "^1.1.2",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^12.1.2",
    "angular-split": "^3.0.3",
    "bootstrap": "^4.5.0",
    "firebase": "^7.17.1",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "^5.6.1",
    "ngx-translate-multi-http-loader": "^3.0.0",
    "querybase": "^0.6.0",
    "rxjs": "~6.5.4",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/architect": "^0.1000.4",
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.1000.4",
    "@angular/cli": "~10.0.4",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~10.0.5",
    "@angular/language-service": "~10.0.5",
    "@types/jasmine": "^3.5.11",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "^12.12.53",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.0",
    "firebase-tools": "^8.0.0",
    "fuzzy": "^0.1.3",
    "inquirer": "^6.2.2",
    "inquirer-autocomplete-prompt": "^1.0.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.5.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "~5.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "~3.3.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
    "open": "^7.1.0",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "~3.9.7"
  }
}
```

just did `npm uninstall @angular/fire`

then did `npm i @angular/fire`

then did `npm update`

deleted `package-lock.json`

and again did `npm i`

Comment: show package json pls and tell us your angular version. And tell what commands u used to install firestoremodule

Comment: Sure let me update it in question

Comment: Hi @sagat I have updated the question let me know if you need anything else thanks

Comment: Sure let me check and revert to you..!! Thanks for the suggestion

Comment: hi @sagat still I updated the package.json and now it looks like EDIT-1 but has the same error):

Comment: Also wrote the steps what I performed after your comments in EDIT-1

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218758/discussion-between-sagat-and-kushal-baldev).

Comment: is `AppModule.ts` listing correct? I don't see `@NgModule()` annotation. Anyways, I also see that the required `AngularFirestoreModule` in the `imports` array is commented. Please double check and edit your question with clean code - remove commented executable code in the question to keep it simple.

Comment: Yes I kept commentef just to show that it works only if commented the problem is there only

Answer (score 2):

Remove **AngularFirestore** from App.module.ts completely from import and from imports array and clean restart using npm run start or ng serve. In app.module.ts file only **modules** can be imported.

Remove it from app.module.ts

**import { AngularFirestore } from '@angular/fire/firestore';**

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
npm install firebase angularfire2 @types/firebase
```

Referred: [Angular, Firebase and AngularFire Crash Course - Learn Why Firebase might change the way we think about Web Development](https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-2-firebase/)